# How do I load XML into a HTML page?

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer-9

What is the best practice for loading XML into a HTML page?  For instance, loading the combined contents of a file.xml and file.xsl into a div or some part of a HTML page.

Answers can be IE-specific, as long as they work on IE9.

Comment: To display the contents of the XML file.  The XSL file would convert the XML into valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `<iframe>` seems like the obvious solution.